# Page Layout in Yii2

Tags: yii2

Contents are going under the top Navigation bar. Sometimes it shows right. Sometimes the problem occurs. Please help. Attaching picture of the error page.I am giving my views/layout/main file below. The content of the page is a bit in upward direction. [image]

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
use common\widgets\Alert;
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
use yii\helpers\Url;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'GM Pharmaceuticals',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
    ]);
    $menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
    ];
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
    } else {
        $menuItems[] = [
            'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
            'url' => ['/site/logout'],
            'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
        ];
    }
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
    ?>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= Alert::widget() ?>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">


            <?php
             echo SideNav::widget([      

                'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
                'heading' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Menu',


                'items' => [
                    [
                        'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                        'label' => 'Home',
                        'icon' => 'home',
                    ],
                    [                       
                        'label' => 'Product',
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula',
                        //'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_add-parties'),
                        'items' => [
                                [
                                    'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=batchno/productbatch/create',
                                    'label' => 'New Batch',
                                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign',
                                    'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('c_billing-person'), 
                                ],
                                [
                                    'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=batchno/productbatch',
                                    'label' => 'Edit Batch',
                                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit',
                                    'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('c_billing-person'), 
                                ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    [                       
                        'label' => 'Party',
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user',
                        //'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_add-parties'),
                        'items' => [
                                [
                                    'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=Parties/parties',
                                    'label' => 'New Party',
                                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign',
                                    'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_add-parties'), 
                                ],
                        ],
                    ], 
                    [
                        'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=tc/bills',
                        'label' => 'Transport',
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-send',
                        'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('c_billing-person'),
                    ], 
                    [                       
                        'label' => 'Payment',
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-piggy-bank',
                        'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('c_payment-collection'),
                        'items' => [
                                [
                                    //'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=payment/payment',
                                    'label' => 'Gopalbabu',
                                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-usd',
                                    'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_create-payment'),
                                    'items' =>[

                                        [
                                            'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=payment/payment/create',
                                            'label' => 'New',
                                            'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign',
                                            'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_create-payment'), 
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=payment/payment',
                                            'label' => 'View & Update',
                                            'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit',
                                            'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_create-payment'), 
                                        ],

                                    ],
                                ],
                                [
                                    //'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=sbp/payments',
                                    'label' => 'Sanatbabu',
                                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-usd',
                                    'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_create-payment'),
                                    'items' =>[
                                        [
                                          'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=sbp%2Fpayments%2Fcreate',
                                          'label' => 'New',
                                          'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign',
                                          'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_create-payment'),
                                        ], 
                                        [
                                          'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=sbp/payments',
                                          'label' => 'View & Update',
                                          'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit',
                                          'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('s_create-payment'),
                                        ], 
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],
                    ], 


                    [
                        'label' => 'Help',
                        'icon' => 'question-sign',
                        'items' => [
                            ['label' => 'About', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
                            ['label' => 'Contact', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],


         ]);  
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-10" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-left">&copy; My Company <?= date('Y') ?></p>

        <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p>
    </div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed `<div class="container-fluid">` to `<div class="container">` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have missed a `<div>`,

try `<br>` tag after main div in `views/layout/main.php`

or check one by one all divs starting and closing properly.

Comment: Hi Shahzad, I've added views/layout/main.php in the question. Please have a look.